# Multithreading in Java : Only one thread gets executed properly and other thread gets terminated

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is the problem statement :

Write  a  java  program  using  threads  to  compute  the  first  25  prime  numbers,  and  to 
compute  the  first  50  Fibonacci  numbers.  Set  the  priority  of  thread  that  computes 
Fibonacci number to 8 and the other to 5. After calculating 30 Fibonacci numbers, make 
that  thread  to  sleep  and  take  up  prime  number  computation.  After  computing  the  25 
prime numbers continue the Fibonacci number computing.

My code:

```
class Fibo{
    private int n=1,a=-1,b=1,c;
    synchronized void disp(){
        for(int i=0;i<=45;i++){
            if(n==31)
                try{
                    System.out.println("Fibonacci Generation Halted");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Caught interrupted exception");
                }
            c=a+b;
            System.out.println(n+" Fibo : "+c);
            a=b;
            b=c;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
class Prime{
    int n=1;
    boolean isPrime=true;
    synchronized void disp(){
        for(int i=2;;i++){
            for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++){
                if((i%j)==0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime){
                System.out.println(n+" Prime : "+i);
                n++;
                if(n==25){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class PrimeThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    Prime p1;
    PrimeThread(){
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        p1=new Prime();
        p1.disp();
    }
}
class FiboThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t2;
    Fibo f;
    FiboThread(){
        t2=new Thread(this);
        t2.setPriority(8);
        t2.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        f=new Fibo();
        f.disp();
    }
}
class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FiboThread ft=new FiboThread();
        PrimeThread pt=new PrimeThread();
    }
}

OUTPUT:
1 Fibo : 0
2 Fibo : 1
3 Fibo : 1
4 Fibo : 2
5 Fibo : 3
6 Fibo : 5
7 Fibo : 8
8 Fibo : 13
9 Fibo : 21
10 Fibo : 34
11 Fibo : 55
12 Fibo : 89
13 Fibo : 144
14 Fibo : 233
15 Fibo : 377
16 Fibo : 610
1 Prime : 2
17 Fibo : 987
2 Prime : 3
18 Fibo : 1597
19 Fibo : 2584
20 Fibo : 4181
21 Fibo : 6765
22 Fibo : 10946
23 Fibo : 17711
24 Fibo : 28657
25 Fibo : 46368
26 Fibo : 75025
27 Fibo : 121393
28 Fibo : 196418
29 Fibo : 317811
30 Fibo : 514229
Fibonacci Generation Halted
31 Fibo : 832040
32 Fibo : 1346269
33 Fibo : 2178309
34 Fibo : 3524578
35 Fibo : 5702887
36 Fibo : 9227465
37 Fibo : 14930352
38 Fibo : 24157817
39 Fibo : 39088169
40 Fibo : 63245986
41 Fibo : 102334155
42 Fibo : 165580141
43 Fibo : 267914296
44 Fibo : 433494437
45 Fibo : 701408733
46 Fibo : 1134903170
```

I was expecting the rest of the prime numbers to be printed when fibonacci thread halts,but that didn't happen, what might be the reason behind this?

Comment: Not that it will help, but what's the point of declaring your two `disp()` methods to be `synchronized`?

Comment: I suggest that you do a little re-factoring.  Get rid of the boolean isPrime variable, and write a `private boolean isPrime(int p)` function.  Then test that function in a single-threaded program before trying to use it in the multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reseting the prime boolean

```
class Prime{
    int n=1;
    boolean isPrime=true;
    synchronized void disp(){
        for(int i=2;;i++){
            isPrime=true; // YOU NEED TO RESET THIS!!!
            for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++){
                if((i%j)==0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime){
                System.out.println(n+" Prime : "+i);
                n++;
                if(n==25){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This fixes the problem... I've got no idea why someone downclicked it